# What is the difference between こだわり and 良｛よ｝い?

Tags: grammar, usage

Consider for example [this article](http://www.weeklybiz.us/business/post-13686/) with the following headline.

> 〈ＪＡＬ〉機内食、**こだわり**の冬メニュー登場
>
> 日本航空（ＪＡＬ）は「空の上のレストラン」をコンセプトに展開している機内食「スカイオーベルジュ BEDD（ベッド） by JAL」で12月１日から提供される冬の**こだわり**メニューを発表した。
>   [...]

What is the difference between こだわり and 良い? Both seem to mean "good" in certain contexts. But when should you use which?

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken something, however こだわり means "obsession, fixating" etc, from the verb こだわる "to be obsessive, to be particular about". You can see examples of the usage [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%93%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A&ref=sa).

Comment: こだわり I found in sentence こだわりの冬メニュー登場.

Comment: I think that when we talk about the food with こだわり, we focus not on as much on the food itself, but more on the quality of the ingredients, the taste of the food etc. So guess it would be "finely selected menu", I also found the translation - "fastidious", so I'd say "fastidious winter menu".

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come to the conclusion that it means "good"?  Did a dictionary say so?  Is that your own personal inference based on context?

Comment: @DarkAkira The nuance/usage of the word has shifted from being fairly negative to mostly positive during the last couple of decades, which is why some of the definitions you have given seem "off" -- "obsession", "fastidious", etc.  Bilingual dictionaries have not caught up with the change, I reckon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very different, in short.

「良い」 just means "good".  It does not say in what way something is good.

「こだわり」 is a noun meaning, in my own words, "being very selective, paying much attention to details, etc." .  There is a sense of exclusiveness and/or aesthetics associated with the word.  It is often used in advertising.